# useLazyQuery onCompleted doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I am running the query **every 1 minute** to check the progress.

```
let timer = null
const [inProgress, setInProgress] = useState(false)

const [
  checkProgress,
  { loading2, data2 }
] = useLazyQuery(CHECK_PROGRESS, {
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      if(data.progress.completed) {
        setInProgress(false)

        // some code
      } else {
        // some code
      }
    }
  }
)

useEffect(() => {
  if (inProgress) {
    timer = setInterval(() => {
      checkProgress()
    }, 1000 * 60)
  } else {
    clearInterval(timer)
  }
  return () => {
    clearInterval(timer)
  }
}, [inProgress])
```

**onCompleted** doesn't trigger once data.progress.completed is changed from false to true.

But the query is still running **every 1 minute**.

Any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was on the backend. I was setting `null` for `non-null` field.
I found the error after adding `onError` callback.

```js
onError: (error) => {
  console.log(error)
}
```